# Automatically write attribute when creating features in QGIS

Tags: attribute-table, fields-attributes, qgis-3

Using QGIS 3.0 I have to draw a lot of features on the map and these features have attributes that change with each entry. However, there is a part of the attribute that is the same for all features. How do I automatically write this part of the attribute in the attribute table when creating a new point?

Example:

```
S1_00001
S1_00002
...
S1_0000N
```

The `S1_` is always the same and can be in a different column as the serial numbering.

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: You need to give some information on your working environment ~ software? scripting? etc

Comment: I use QGIS 3.0 and

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the field default value.

Open the `layer properties`, go to the `field` tab and click on the field `Text Edit` then set the default. Remember that text should be enclosed in single quotes.

You can also derive the value of a field based on other fields (if they all have a default). Assuming you have a column `a` and `b` you can set the default of column `c` as `"a" || "b"` (note the double quotes to refer to a field)

Now when you create a new features, the default will be used- and you are free to modify it or to keep it as is.

[image: field properties]

[image: Default value]

[image: Derive default]

Comment: Which also works with my suggested "code". Neat =)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're using QGis: You can't get automatical entries in QGis, at least not that easy. If you're working with a database, you could create a trigger which adds a value, but I neither now how, nor if your desired input would be possible.

What you can do, is the following: Create all your features, then use the field calculator with the following expression

```
concat('S1_',lpad(to_string($id),5,'0'))
```

concat puts two strings together, lpad fills up the left side of a string to a given number (here 5) with a desired character (here 0), and $id simply is the ID of your entry.